# Adding a user-entered number in a scanner line directly to the right instead of the line underneath?

Tags: java

I am having trouble with a user-entered number. I am trying to add the user-entered number a few spaces after the colon in the sentence instead of the line underneath.

```
Scanner inputHere = new Scanner(system.in);
System.out.println("I am trying to add the number a few spaces after the colon:");
String inputHereOne = inputHere.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
System.out.println("I am trying to add the number a few spaces after the colon:");
```

to not print a newline - you should also `flush()` when you do so. Like,

```
System.out.print("I am trying to add the number a few spaces after the colon: ");
System.out.flush();
```

Also, you had a typo here

```
new Scanner(system.in);
```

should be

```
new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: The system.out.flush(); did not move the user-input number to the right of the colon in the sentence.

Comment: No. The `System.out.print` (no `ln`) does that. The `System.out.flush` is required because auto-flush is triggered on newline.

Answer (score 1):

Change the lowercase 's' in  'system.in' to 'System.in'

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.nextLine();
```